# Repeat rows cumulative

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table

```
| date       | id | number |
|------------|----|--------|
| 2021/05/01 | 1  | 10     |
| 2021/05/02 | 2  | 20     |
| 2021/05/03 | 3  | 30     |
| 2021/05/04 | 1  | 20     |
```

I am trying to write a query to have this other table

```
| date       | id | number |
|------------|----|--------|
| 2021/05/01 | 1  | 10     |
| 2021/05/02 | 1  | 10     |
| 2021/05/02 | 2  | 20     |
| 2021/05/03 | 1  | 10     |
| 2021/05/03 | 2  | 20     |
| 2021/05/03 | 3  | 30     |
| 2021/05/04 | 1  | 20     |
| 2021/05/04 | 2  | 20     |
| 2021/05/04 | 3  | 30     |
```

The idea is that each date should have all the previus different ids with its number, and if an id is repeated then only the last value should be considered.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to expand out all the rows for each date.  Then take the most recent value using `qualify`:

```
with t as (
    select date '2021-05-01' as date, 1 as id, 10 as number union all
    select date '2021-05-02' as date, 2 as id, 20 as number union all
    select date '2021-05-03' as date, 3 as id, 30 as number union all
    select date '2021-05-04' as date, 1 as id, 20 as number
)
select d.date, t.id, t.number 
from t join
     (select date
      from (select min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
            from t
           ) tt cross join 
           unnest(generate_date_array(min_date, max_date, interval 1 day)) date
     ) d
     on t.date <= d.date
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by d.date, t.id order by t.date desc) = 1
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

A more efficient method doesn't generate all the rows and then filter them.  Instead, it just generates the rows that are needed by generating the appropriate dates *within* each row.  That requires a couple of window functions to get the "next" date for each id and the maximum date in the data:

```
with t as (
    select date '2021-05-01' as date, 1 as id, 10 as number union all
    select date '2021-05-02' as date, 2 as id, 20 as number union all
    select date '2021-05-03' as date, 3 as id, 30 as number union all
    select date '2021-05-04' as date, 1 as id, 20 as number
)
select date, t.id, t.number 
from (select t.*,
             date_add(lead(date) over (partition by id order by date), interval -1 day) as next_date,
             max(date) over () as max_date
      from t 
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(date, coalesce(next_date, max_date))) date
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below [less verbose] approach

```
select t1.date, t2.id, t2.number
from (
  select *, array_agg(struct(date, id,number)) over(order by date) arr
  from `project.dataset.table`
) t1, unnest(arr) t2
where true 
qualify row_number() over (partition by t1.date, t2.id order by t2.date desc) = 1
# order by date, id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]